# checked='checked' not working with knockout checked data-binding for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockout in my code and there's a foreach loop in which there are several radio buttons, I'm accessing the first button by $index property. I want this first radio button to be checked by default on load. but there's also a "checked" data-binding with an attribute.

following is the code snippet:

```
<input type="radio" checked='checked' name="foo" data-bind="value: $data.methodId, checked: $parent.checkout.valueImp">
```

the radio button doesn't get checked by default. Is there a way by which I can by default put this radio button as 'checked' on load and simultaneously the data-bind also works.

Comment: Better do it in your JS code (also more readable than cryptic values in your `data-bind`)

Answer (score 0):

> the radio button doesn't get checked by default

That's because you've bound its checked state to a viewmodel property. To make it checked by default, give `$parent.checkout.valueImp` the value of this radio button by default.

Example:

```js
var vm = {
  value1: ko.observable("one"),
  value2: ko.observable("two"),
  currentValue: ko.observable("two") // <===
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
Note that Two is checked by default:
<div id="container">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="x" data-bind="value: value1, checked: currentValue"> One
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="x" data-bind="value: value2, checked: currentValue"> Two
  </label>
  <div>Curent value: <span data-bind="text: currentValue"></span></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way by which this data-bind can assign the `value` to `$parent.checkout.valueImp` by default through `checked='checked' `

Comment: @N.Y.: Not that I'm aware of. The model sets the initial state of the view, not the other way around. It would be possible to create a different custom binding to do that, but the built-in `value` binding doesn't. And I'd argue it doesn't make sense; provide the default in the model, not the view.